# Translation - "From" and "To" to Russian for a converter app

Tags: перевод

[image: Screenshot]

I have an Android App which converts numbers from one number system to another. I want to translate it into Russian. All I need is translation of two words-
"From"
"To"

I used Google Translation services and got some results but when I translated them back to English, they did not give "From" and "To" as results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*(assuming you need something like HEX→Dec)*

- **из** + *Genitive* **в** + *Accusative*. For example, *"из шестнадцатеричной в двоичную" = "from hexadecimal to binary"*

Note that if you do not use a radio button list or a list of abbreviations, that requires oblique forms of words for "base 2", "base 8", "base10", "base 16". Though, they all will end in "-ой" for Genitive and "-ую" for Accusative (instead of "ая" in dictionary form). Again, this only applies if you use whole words and try to sound all natural, like writing it all in a single line or a sentence like "I want to convert 511 from *decimal* to *binary*". A simple interface like "511, from:Dec, to:HEX" may use just abbreviations or dictionary forms.

If you are planning to use Russian words for number systems (and do it grammatically) here's the way:

- look up the required word in the dictionary. Since "number system" is feminine in Russian, you would actually use "-ая" ending, not "-ый/-ий" (bin = двоичная, oct = восьмеричная, dec = десятичная, hex = шестнадцатеричная)
- replace **-ая** with **-ой** for the words in the first list
- replace **-ая** with **-ую** for the words in the second list
- DONE!
- makes sense to keep the two lists separate for all languages. Russian is not the only one where the forms are going to be different
- in Japanese people use postpositions, not prepositions, so you probably will need analogues like "source" and "result" rather than から and に

Comment: I have zero knowledge about Russian. All I need to know is that which Russian words should be used for replacing the placeholders "From:" and "To:"

Comment: I have updated the question with a screenshot.

Comment: Are you planning on translating names of number systems as well? **Из** (from) and **В** (to) will work either way. Just remember that some languages use different forms of "decimal" for source and target state of an action. So it may sound a bit awkward if you just use dictionary feminine forms everywhere (двоичн**ая**, восьмеричн**ая**, десятичн**ая**, шестнадцатеричн**ая**— bin, oct, dec, hex). Changing "-ая" to "-ой" for the first dropdown list and "-ую" for the second one makes it completely grammatical.

Comment: No I don't want to translate the names of the number systems, only the words "FROM" and "TO". SO what should I replace them with?

Comment: With **из** and **в**, as I said at the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

To the Shady_arc's answer I'll add that in case of mail and similar,

From X to Y -> От Х (in Genitive) Y (in Dative)

i. e. From Vasya To Petya -> От Васи Пете

In case you cannot do cases (i.e. X and Y are nicks), I'd suggest:

```
От: X
Кому: Y
```

Comment: I have updated the question with a screenshot. So should I replace From: with От: and To: with Кому: .Please answer with respect to the screenshot uploaded.